# Photoshop Animation Stacks Frames on Second Loop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I'm trying to create a gif in Photoshop using timeline. I have it set to loop forever. It works perfectly the first loop, but has problems once it hits the second (or subsequent) loop. The first frame will show fine, as will the third (or any later) frame. However, the *second* frame always shows on top of the first frame. If I add a background to the gif, this problem doesn't occur, it only happens if the gif is transparent.

Does anyone know why this occurs? It's always the second frame only of every loop after the first run-through of the gif animation.

[image: Stacked frame]

Here is the gif (you can see it "glitch" where the frame gets stacked):

[image: Problematic Gif]

Comment: Could you insert the gif at the question please?

Comment: Added gif. It wouldn't let me add the photoshop file, but hopefully this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Frame disposal method

> The frame disposal method specifies whether to discard the current frame before displaying the next frame. You select a disposal method for animations that include background transparency to specify whether the current frame will be visible through the transparent areas of the next frame.

The problem is in the frame #1:

- Check at the frame's bottom, there are two different icons

[image]

- Click at the frame #1 disposal icon with the right mouse button and set it as the other frames: **Dispose**. Or select all the frames and set them as **Automatic**.

[image: Disposal icon]   [image: SQUIRREL]

> **Automatic**
>
> Determines a disposal method for the current frame automatically, discarding the current frame if the next frame contains layer transparency. For most animations, the Automatic option (default) yields the desired results.
>
> **Do Not Dispose**
>
> Preserves the current frame as the next frame is added to the display. The current frame (and preceding frames) may show through transparent areas of the next frame. Use a browser to see an accurate preview of an animation using the Do Not Dispose option.
>
> **Dispose**
>
> Discards the current frame from the display before the next frame is displayed. Only a single frame is displayed at any time (and the current frame does not appear through the transparent areas of the next frame).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is extremely clear!